# return statement javascript

Tags: javascript

Why is that when I return a function I can't have more code beneath it

sample

```
<script language="javascript">
    return compute();
    alert(1);
</script>
```

The alert will not work

Comment: Because `return` can only be used within a function context.

Answer (score 3):

> The alert will not work

Sounds right to me.  I envision this code as:

```
    (function() {
      return compute();
      alert(1);
    })();
```

Comment: Don't you want to flip those two lines? Returning as the first line, I believe, will prevent the `alert(1)` from happening.

Comment: @normalocity Yes, but that was not the intent of the question.  I was just trying to affirm that the alert will NOT work.

Answer (score 2):

The function of the `return` statement is twofold. First, it returns a value (in this case, a pointer to a function). Second, it is to manage [control flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow), which is to say, it tells the browser that's executing that code to leave that function, and return execution control to the piece of code that called your example script.

To say it another way, trying to return a value, while also expecting to continue execution, makes it ambiguous to the browser what to do next.

If you were to flip the two lines (alert first, THEN return a value), that would cause both lines to be executed.

[This tutorial](http://www.golivecentral.com/pages/txttut/jstut/return.shtml) may also provide further insight.

Also, as [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w) and [Kris Krause](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139547/kris-krause) noted, you can only `return` from a function, yet the code you've shown is not wrapped in a function.

Comment: Small correction: in this case (I assume the OP's example) the return value is whatever `compute()` returns, not necessarily a function. `return compute;` would return the `compute()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of a function/closure, you *can* have code beneath your return statement.  Specifically, function declarations that will be hoisted, so that they will be available for use by the code above the return.  I use this "pattern" all the time, here is a small example from my current code base:

```
function msgHandlers() {
    var scope
        ,msgs;

    return {
        SET_CONTEXT: function(context) {
            scope = context.scope;
            msgs = context.messages;
        }

        ,SUBSCRIBE_ALL: function() {
            me.subscribe(scope, msgs.ITEM_PINNED, itemPinnedHandler);
        }
    }

    function itemPinnedHandler(record) {
        loadInventoryRecord(record);    
    }
}
```